# Authentification Active Directory Azure on an old Asp.net WebSite

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, web, azure-active-directory

I've some issues finding information on how I can use Windows Azure Active Directory authentification in an existing, old, Asp.net WebSite.

The framework is .net 3.5 and the website use Asp Webforms.
I just want the user to authentificate through a simple aspx page...
The Windows Azure Active Directory already exists.
Do you know if it's possible?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to bump up to .Net 4.5.1 for any runtime support. 
Katana and Asp.Net Core 1.0 supports OpenIdConnect and JwtBearer

http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/
https://github.com/aspnet/home

ADAL supports obtaining access_tokens.
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet

Comment: Hi thanks for your time, Are you sure there is no possibility to do this without bumping to .Net 4.5.1? It's an old application and it's not possible to do this...